# How to organize laptop mouse cable?

Tags: laptop, mouse

I used to own a Logitech G9x mouse that I used with a desktop, and I loved the mouse, but the wire had many problems, it would never lay correctly and part of the rubber insulation started to bulge out of the nylon shield.  Well, that mouse was stolen from me a while ago.

Recently I just ordered my first (gaming) laptop and another G9x.  The laptop has a nicely placed USB port on the  right side of the computer towards the rear.  I want a way to keep the wire on my mouse wound up so there won't be any creases in the wire that will cause the problems my old one had.

I use my mouse with my right hand so it will be very close to the USB port.

<del>I have been looking around and found the expensive [Razer Armadillo 2](http://www.razerzone.com/gaming-accessories/razer-armadillo-ii) that is advertised as a wire management system, does anyone know how it works?  Could it be used to keep my mouse's wire organized and safe?</del>

What are some cheep wire management systems that would look nice and function well?

Comment: How about a YouTube review video? See: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfK5QYnkmBc You might also want to look into a new mouse pad, one that has this kind of feature built-in to it.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it isn't really what I'm looking for though.

Comment: Why not simply buy a wireless mouse? That eliminates your problem entirely. There are plenty of gaming grade wireless mice available now, a few of them are offered by razer.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that.  And lets be real, "gaming grade" is mostly a marketing point, but I love the feel of the G9x.

Comment: @LeeHarrison That would be the ideal solution in my opinion. Ever since I went wireless I never looked back. I didn't like changing batteries, which I thought of as the only disadvantage with wireless over wired mice. I didn't play games on the computer at that time and the games were not very demanding. But I got used to changing batteries after a while. Then computer mice started getting better battery life, and also better precision. The only drawback today might be the price and possibly RF interference.

Comment: Have either of you ever used a G9x?  A few of my friends used to bash it because of the price, but now a few of them own it because they like the feel of it so much!  Besides, I got it for 54$ on eBay - and a wireless mouse that feels as nice would probably cost over $100.  One other thing I don't like too much about wireless mice is that most of them are much smaller than a desktop mouse, and I like a mouse that I don't have to hold with my fingertips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've been doing some research and I cam across something that is perfect what I want.  The [Dotz Cord Wrapper Mini](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0085U9DO6) is a little box with a centerpole to wrap up usb wires.  The photo even shows it doing exactly what I was looking for.

**edit:**
I kept on looking around and also found an entire company that only makes one product!  The [Applecore wrapper](http://www.apple-cores.com/pages/Products.html). I actually like this even better than the Dotz wrapper.  It is a little spool in the shape of an apple core that allows for nice wire keeping.  The advantage to this system is that it is completely round so there are no rough edges to scratch or crease the wire.

Comment: That's neat! You may want to check out Blue Lounge. See: http://www.bluelounge.com/ Their CableBox is very popular here in Sweden. They are headquartered in Singapore but their main market is in Europe and they also have US presence. The CableBox is not exactly what you are looking for, this is more for TV and HiFi. But they have something called Cableyoyo that might be interesting.

Comment: Thanks, I checked out the CableYoYo.  It looks like a good product, but I want something small that I can carry around.  That looked like it was more intended for desk use.

Comment: There are lots of these devices out there.  I use one for my headset when traveling.  One issue arises from these devices though.  When winding cords around them, the rubber/plastic/whatever cords themselves will eventually start to stay in this position.  So when the cords are removed from the holder, they will not stay flat.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  I can try to wrap it different directions every few weeks, just so it doesn't stay in one position.